# JPA(Hibernate) cannot select Enum Type

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class MusicInfo
{
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private MusicDifficulty difficulty;
}

public enum MusicDifficulty
{
   EASY, NOMAL
}
```

.

```
jpa-ql> SELECT mi.difficulty FROM MusicInfo as mi
[2022-08-10 17:14:20] 24 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 242 ms (execution: 208 ms, fetching: 34 ms)
```

[image]

When enum type is inquired, the result exists, but the column cannot be retrieved.

What should I do to select the enum type?

Comment: Provide the code where you get the records, please. And show the SQL log from Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If you create enum like this

```
public enum Currency {
    EUR,
    USD
}
```

then problem another place

Comment: You don't need the `label` to use enums with Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: This issue has not been resolved. It's been confirmed that it's not being looked up only within Intellij IDEA, my guess.

Comment: What does ```label``` mean? Do you mean ```@Enumerated```?